# How to solve this partial derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function
$u(x,t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$\int_{0}^\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}} e^{-s^2}ds$
satisfies the partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = K\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$

where $K$ is a positive constant number. Find the value of $K$.

The value of $K$ that I calculated isn't a constant. Can anyone please help with this question?
Thank you so much!

Comment: If pde, you should use $\partial$

Comment: Did you know that you can enclose entire expressions in dollar signs, rather than just a single fraction it w integral at a time? The result will also look nicer, as spacing and font size matches better. For instance, `$\frac{du}{dt} = K\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$` yields $\frac{du}{dt} = K\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$, compared to your $\frac{du}{dt} $ = K$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just compute the derivatives: For fixed $t>0$ consider the function $v(x)=u(x,t)$. Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, $v'(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{t}}$. Differentiating once again yields $v''(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{t}}\frac{-2x}{t}e^{-\frac{x^2}{t}}=-\frac{4x}{\sqrt{\pi} t^{\frac{3}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{t}}$.
In the same way, for fixed $x$ consider $h(t)=u(x,t)$. Once again, by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, $h'(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{-x}{2t^{\frac{3}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{t}}=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}t^{\frac{3}{2}}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{t}}$. Now, note that $v''=\partial_{xx}u$ and $h'=\partial_t u$ so that comparing the expression yields $K=\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

$$u(x,t)=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^{\frac x{\sqrt t}}e^{-s^2}\,\mathrm ds$$

$$\implies\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac2{\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}t}\implies\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=-\frac{4x}{t\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}t}$$

$$\implies\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\frac x{t\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}t}$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=K\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\iff-1=-4K\implies K=\frac14$$